# Handling IDisposables within another IDisposable "using" statement

Tags: c#

I'm still relatively new to C# and have only within the past several days been exposed to "IDisposables". I can grasp the concept of the `using` block to take care of objects which must be disposed of without needing to manually remember to call the `.Dispose()` method - convenient!

Let's say though that I start with a new `SqlConnection` which I handle within a `using` statement. Within that block of code I create some additional IDisposables, for example a `SqlDataAdapter`. Does that adapter need it's own `using` statement?

For example, if I have code...

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    // Do things
}
```

... will `myCommand` and `myAdapter` be disposed of when `myConnection` is disposed (since they are within the scope of that code block)? Or do I need multiple `using` statements, maybe something like:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            // Do things
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you need multiple using block so that each object dispose function is invoked when the scope of using block ends.

Comment: Note that the need to remember to Dispose() just shifts to the need to remember `using() {}`. The main plusses of this are readability and exception-safety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it would indeed be best to dispose all of them. However, you can avoid the indenting by nesting them directly:

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection())
using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand())
using (var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    // Do things
}
```

Alternatively, specifically in the case of ADO.NET (which does, let's be fair, have a lot of disposable types), you might find it easier to use one of the libraries that hides away a lot of the plumbing - for example, with "dapper":

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    return conn.Query<Customer>(
        "select * from Customers where Region=@region",
        new { region }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does that adapter need it's own using statement?

In this case, no. But that depends on detailed knowledge of the Connection and Adapter objects so as a **best practice**: use one `using()` per `IDisposable`. Even for MemoryStream where `Dispose()` does nothing. They are inexpensive.

Your code is correct but we usually economize on the `{}` :

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection())
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand())    
using (SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    // Do things
}
```

We use the rule here that when a `using()` controls 1 statement (the next `using()`), you don't need braces. And then we fudge on the indentation a little.

Answer (score 0):

**Using** is just syntatic sugar for

```
            var connection = new Connection();
        try
        {
            connection.DoSomething();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Check for a null resource.
            if (connection != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
            }
        }
```

So yes, you need nested using statements to be sure to dispose all of these